Консоль не работает в Pycharm 2024.1.2
Не так давно я установил Pycharm 2024.1.2 на замену Pycharm 2022. Запускаю консоль, а она выдает ошибку:
C:/python-3.12.3-embed-amd64\python.exe “C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py” --mode=client --host=127.0.0.0.1 --port=62166 
Traceback (last last last call):
  File “C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2024.1.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py”, line 4, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle._pydev_getopt import gnu_getopt
ModuleNotFoundError: There is no module named '_pydev_bundle'
Failed to connect to the console process.
The process terminated with exit code 1

Проблема в интерпретаторе или в самом приложении?





Тут (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53500500/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pydevd-bundle) советуют переименовать каталог: "Это абсолютно связано с тем, что ваши файлы содержат каталог с именем code! Имя конфликтует с системным пакетом. Просто измените код имени каталога на любое другое имя." Подскажите какой каталог переименовать или папку?
